# How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?

Tags: contract-deployment, addresses, create2, create

How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?  What use cases are there for knowing a contract's address in advance?

Comment: In addition to @eth [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761) it should be noted that you take last 20 bytes.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

**EDIT Sept 2023**: `CREATE2` information clarified.

**EDIT January 2022**: Updated Solidity syntax to ^0.8.0.

The address for an Ethereum contract is **deterministically** computed from the address of its creator (`sender`) and how many transactions the creator has sent (`nonce`).  The `sender` and `nonce` are RLP encoded and then **hashed with Keccak-256**.

From [pyethereum:](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/782842758e219e40739531a5e56fff6e63ca567b/ethereum/utils.py)

```
def mk_contract_address(sender, nonce):
    return sha3(rlp.encode([normalize_address(sender), nonce]))[12:]
```

In Solidity:

```
nonce0= address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd6), bytes1(0x94), _origin, bytes1(0x80))))));
nonce1= address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xd6), bytes1(0x94), _origin, bytes1(0x01))))));
```

[Example](https://swende.se/blog/Ethereum_quirks_and_vulns.html) with some discussion:

For sender 0x6ac7ea33f8831ea9dcc53393aaa88b25a785dbf0, the contract addresses that it will create are the following:

```
nonce0= "0xcd234a471b72ba2f1ccf0a70fcaba648a5eecd8d"
nonce1= "0x343c43a37d37dff08ae8c4a11544c718abb4fcf8"
nonce2= "0xf778b86fa74e846c4f0a1fbd1335fe81c00a0c91"
nonce3= "0xfffd933a0bc612844eaf0c6fe3e5b8e9b6c1d19c"
```

In Java with Web3j:

```
private String calculateContractAddress(String address, long nonce){
    byte[] addressAsBytes = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(address);

    byte[] calculatedAddressAsBytes =
            Hash.sha3(RlpEncoder.encode(
                    new RlpList(
                            RlpString.create(addressAsBytes),
                            RlpString.create((nonce)))));

    calculatedAddressAsBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(calculatedAddressAsBytes,
            12, calculatedAddressAsBytes.length);
    String calculatedAddressAsHex = Numeric.toHexString(calculatedAddressAsBytes);
    return calculatedAddressAsHex;
}
```

**Note**: As per [EIP 161 A Specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-161.md#specification) **contract** accounts are initiated with **nonce = 1** (in the mainnet). So the first contract address, created by another contract, will be computed with non-zero nonce.

---

## `CREATE2`

A new opcode, `CREATE2` was added in [EIP-1014](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md) that is another way that a contract can be created.

For contract created by `CREATE2` its address will be:

`keccak256( 0xff ++ address(this) ++ salt ++ keccak256(init_code))[12:]`

More information will be added here and for the meantime see [EIP-1014](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md).

Comment: For the usecase part, you could mention something about prefunding contracts

Comment: What if the creator is a contract itself? Has the address also a nonce? Is it increased by every call it makes or only with the creation of new contacts? Or is the address and nonce of tx.origin relevant?

Comment: @TjadenHess Thanks, upvoted instead of explaining prefunding more.

Comment: @mKoeppelmann: Same computation if creator is a contract; nonce increases every single transaction an account makes (new contract/account would start at nonce 0), and the address and nonce of earlier senders (such as tx.origin) do not affect address of new contract.

Comment: @eth: "nonce increases every single transaction" this is what confuses me, because in the definition in the yellowpaper only human controlled accounts can make transactions. A transaction is something that is signed with a private key. Contracts can only make calls that are triggered by transactions. So I wonder what "calls" increase the nonce of a contract. All calls or only calls that create a new contract?

Comment: I think the question I am asking is getting a little bit of topic so I created a new question here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/764/do-contracts-also-have-a-nonce

Comment: What happens in the case of a contract creating a contract? Does a contract also have a sequence number?

Comment: @StevenRoose Yes, contracts have nonces. A nonce of a contract is only incremented when that contract creates another contract. It's in separate question Martin asked https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/764/do-contracts-also-have-a-nonce :)

Comment: 0xd6, 0x94, 0x80 and 0x01, what are those magic numbers?

Comment: They are part of the [RLP](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) encoding

Comment: Here is online smart contract address calculator with full CREATE2 support: https://toolkit.abdk.consulting/ethereum#contract-address

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov Thanks, if you have time to post a separate answer, explaining the different fields / how to use your calculator, I will update my CREATE2 answer to point to yours.

Comment: For Solidity ^0.6.0, I had to use `address(uint160(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(byte(0xd6), byte(0x94), _origin, byte(0x80))))))` (for nonce0).

Comment: For calculating address of a contract deployed using `CREATE2` you need to replace `senderAddress` with `address(this)`, i.e. the address of the factory contract (that calls the `CREATE2` opcode) itself. See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/yul.html#opcodes in which it says "current contract’s address".

Comment: i.e. many people may wrongly think `senderAddress` is `msg.sender`, but it really should be `address(this)`. e.g. see Solidity code at https://github.com/axelarnetwork/axelar-gmp-sdk-solidity/blob/d859f6f62ff04c5c40d4508ed72caabf4394f0db/contracts/deploy/Create2.sol#L48-L64

Comment: @SKYBITDEV3 Updated answer, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Thanks to [eth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/42/eth)'s answer, it helped a lot to resolve $2000 issue.

Just solved issue with funds, which were sent in **main** Ethereum network to address of smart contract, deployed to **test** Ethereum network. We used same wallet to deploy different smart contract in **main** Ethereum network several times until transaction field *nonce* achieved the same value 13, as were used to deploy on **test** network. We called special method of freshly deployed smart contract to reclaim funds. So smart contract was deployed after it was really funded: https://etherscan.io/address/0x9c86825280b1d6c7dB043D4CC86E1549990149f9

Just finished an article about this issue: https://medium.com/@k06a/how-we-sent-eth-to-the-wrong-address-and-successfully-recovered-them-2fc18e09d8f6

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. but what if the mainnet contract owner has current nonce higher than the one was used to create contract in testnet. I have same situation as your.. but only probelm is that my main net owner wallet has latest nonce 236 and testnet contract was created at 13 nonce..  is there any way to override and deploy contract having previous nonce?

Comment: At current gas fees, you would pay a fortune to deploy the contract 12 times, before you got to 13. Why did you not set the nonce to 13 right away?

Comment: @Qwerty you can set a nonce yourself for deployment?

Comment: @Sky Yes, in metamask when confirming the transaction. I just tried it with REMIX. If you don't see it in Metamask, enable advanced options.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a node.js script that deterministically computes an Ethereum contract address given the contract creator's public address and nonce value.

Let me know if anyone has questions about inputs, etc.

```js
// node version: v9.10.0
// module versions:
// rlp@2.0.0
// keccak@1.4.0

const rlp = require("rlp");
const keccak = require("keccak");

var nonce = 0x00; //The nonce must be a hex literal!
var sender = "0x6ac7ea33f8831ea9dcc53393aaa88b25a785dbf0"; //Requires a hex string as input!

var input_arr = [sender, nonce];
var rlp_encoded = rlp.encode(input_arr);

var contract_address_long = keccak("keccak256")
  .update(rlp_encoded)
  .digest("hex");

var contract_address = contract_address_long.substring(24); //Trim the first 24 characters.
console.log("contract_address: " + contract_address);
```

Note that the nonce can be incremented normally, just remember that it's a hex value.

Output (nonce = 0x00):

```
contract_address: cd234a471b72ba2f1ccf0a70fcaba648a5eecd8d
```

Output (nonce = 0x01):

```
contract_address: 343c43a37d37dff08ae8c4a11544c718abb4fcf8
```

Comment: What is `rlp` ?

Comment: Here is a good explanation: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19092/why-was-rlp-chosen-as-the-low-level-protocol-encoding-algorithm

Answer (score 6):

Here is updated Python version for modern Ethereum libraries (`eth-utils`):

```py
import rlp
from eth_utils import keccak, to_checksum_address, to_bytes


def mk_contract_address(sender: str, nonce: int) -> str:
    """Create a contract address using eth-utils.

    # https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761/620
    """
    sender_bytes = to_bytes(hexstr=sender)
    raw = rlp.encode([sender_bytes, nonce])
    h = keccak(raw)
    address_bytes = h[12:]
    return to_checksum_address(address_bytes)


print(to_checksum_address(mk_contract_address(to_checksum_address("0x6ac7ea33f8831ea9dcc53393aaa88b25a785dbf0"), 1)))
print("0x343c43a37d37dff08ae8c4a11544c718abb4fcf8")
assert mk_contract_address(to_checksum_address("0x6ac7ea33f8831ea9dcc53393aaa88b25a785dbf0"), 1) == \
    to_checksum_address("0x343c43a37d37dff08ae8c4a11544c718abb4fcf8")
```

Answer (score 4):

RLP done in solidity (did not test this though, beware! just for understanding):

```
    function addressFrom(address _origin, uint _nonce) public pure returns (address) {
        if(_nonce == 0x00)     return address(keccak256(byte(0xd6), byte(0x94), _origin, byte(0x80)));
        if(_nonce <= 0x7f)     return address(keccak256(byte(0xd6), byte(0x94), _origin, byte(_nonce)));
        if(_nonce <= 0xff)     return address(keccak256(byte(0xd7), byte(0x94), _origin, byte(0x81), uint8(_nonce)));
        if(_nonce <= 0xffff)   return address(keccak256(byte(0xd8), byte(0x94), _origin, byte(0x82), uint16(_nonce)));
        if(_nonce <= 0xffffff) return address(keccak256(byte(0xd9), byte(0x94), _origin, byte(0x83), uint24(_nonce)));
        return address(keccak256(byte(0xda), byte(0x94), _origin, byte(0x84), uint32(_nonce))); // more than 2^32 nonces not realistic
    }
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, wonder where did you get those magic numbers: 0x7f, 0xd6, 0x94

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP#definition

Comment: The nonce can never be 0, so that first test can be removed.

Comment: Nonce *starts* with zero, see transactions on etherscan.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure ethers.js implementation in TypeScript, returning a checksummed address. nonce is expected to be a regular `number`.

(ethers.js does have a function called `getContractAddress` too, but it cannot be used for any nonce)

```
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';

static getContractAddress(address: string, nonce: number): string {
    const rlp_encoded = ethers.utils.RLP.encode(
        [address, ethers.BigNumber.from(nonce.toString()).toHexString()]
    );
    const contract_address_long = ethers.utils.keccak256(rlp_encoded);
    const contract_address = '0x'.concat(contract_address_long.substring(26));
    return ethers.utils.getAddress(contract_address);
}
```

Comment: This implementation works in case the nonce is greater than 0. For nonce = 0 the result is not correct (see example and compare with result of the top answer). A simple one-liner that works correctly in ethers.js is `const contractAddress = ethers.utils.getContractAddress({from, nonce});`

Comment: @GongFu yes, better to use the in-built function. At the time I believe I was using an outdated version of Ethers that did not have this function.

Answer (score 1):

The contract address is typically a hash of the sender's address and sender's wallet nonce. The actual contract code doesn't make any difference - the hash is the same regardless of the code.

Above I said *typically* because there are other ways of deploying contracts. If an existing contract deploys a contract with a special opcode `CREATE2` the contract address is calculated a bit differently.

You can check details for example here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/smart-contract-address-creation-method-difference-between-smart-contract-address-and-wallet-97b421506455

Comment: Upvoted but merging with earlier question to gather answers together.

Comment: I already started wondering did I accidentally answer a question with valid previous answers already.

Comment: No problem! Sometimes helpful to merge, sometimes not. Thanks for all your work. (I've upvoted many, but many others do not seem to vote much.)