# Deployed contract not callable anymore

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment

I deployed a contract yesterday which was mined and which was responding to calls. Today the contract "does not live" anymore. Do I need to redeploy? Is there a way to find addresses of contracts I deployed with a specific account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find contract's address?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/how-to-find-contracts-address)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to find your contract is to checkout out the account that created the contract in a blockchain explorer.

For example, inspecting the account [0x5abfec25f74cd88437631a7731906932776356f9](http://etherscan.io/address/0x5abfec25f74cd88437631a7731906932776356f9) will show you that it created the contract [0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae](http://etherscan.io/address/0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae) by its [4th transaction](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x9c81f44c29ff0226f835cd0a8a2f2a7eca6db52a711f8211b566fd15d3e0e8d4).

Answer (score 2):

See
[How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)

You may have been using a different network, like a testnet or tool.  Or if you only interacted with the contract on mainnet for a brief moment after it was mined, it's possible there was a [blockchain reorganization.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-can-a-dapp-detect-a-fork-or-chain-reorganization-using-web3-js-or-additional)

Comment: was deployed to testnet, and tried to call it again from testnet.

Answer (score 1):

If you used the testnet you can search for the contract's address (or the address used to broadcast it) using [etherscan's testnet site](https://testnet.etherscan.io/). If it doesn't show up as a contract creation transaction then the contract was never deployed.

If it was deployed you need **both** the address of the contract and the ABI (for example [this](https://gist.github.com/fivedogit/4f3e9a035262b99b2e7356a4fdf6dd34) is the ABI for the DAO contract).

Using these you can open geth from anywhere and have a local instance of the contract with:

```
var abi = JSON.parse(contracts_abi_string);
var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
```

You can then interact with `myContract`.

Comment: It was deployed, i could call it.

Comment: @TMOTTM Do you still have the ABI? In order to call it you'll need both the contract's address (which it sounds like you have) and the ABI.

Comment: No don't think so. I closed the client since then. In principle it was really just the greeter tutorial example.

Comment: @TMOTTM If you recreate it locally and broadcast it make sure you save the ABI (should be a string of JSON for example [this](https://gist.github.com/fivedogit/4f3e9a035262b99b2e7356a4fdf6dd34) is the ABI for the DAO contract). Then you should be able to reopen geth from anywhere and have a local instance of the contract with: `var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);` where `var abi = JSON.parse(contracts_abi_string);`. You can then call your contracts methods on `myContract`.

Comment: ok cool. I'll consider it.

Comment: Still, a local instance of the contract was not exactly what I was working for. I'm trying to deploy to the blockchain...