# Contract transaction was sent to a 'null' address

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, transactions, contract-deployment

I have attempted to deploy a contract through geth, my understanding was that a null value could be given when creating the transaction to deploy the contract.

After mining the transaction I attempted to look up the transaction via the hash returned by the rcp call, I was given the following response in geth:

```
{
  blockHash: "0x06fe2ca8aae95b44057dbb663bed0faf9e8cc4d33418b21067d64de0eaa02f51",
  blockNumber: 37,
  from: "0x3440825288a9de705e2dbc26e4f6494b4d1f6426",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0x5e4c06e62aa70544f3349f51521e19454d4b43a224a402492cc256b115208391",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 2,
  r: "0x3397da9897ee38d81511288de20e19d9b83ec98c056dc28604726749f350fd97",
  s: "0x44e3a8ef63f6e39118287b74deed6aa5b53f4234ad7f0669680bf9f2a4f7e030",
  to: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x1c",
  value: 0
}
```

Is my understanding of how contract deployment works incorrect? Why is the address null on the blockchain? How can I call the contract or associated methods/functions?

I would be very grateful for any assistance that could be provided, thank you.

Comment: This should help? http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/how-to-find-contracts-address

Comment: I understand if deploying a contract in the geth console you can get the contract address returned, but how can I get the contract address from an rpc call which only returns the transaction hash?

Comment: Surely the blockchain should have the location the transaction was sent somewhere, doesn't seem to be the case when looking up the transaction by it's hash (see above). Any ideas how I should be doing this in regards to rpc calls? Surely I won't have to generate my own contract address before making the rpc call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to mine it?

About half way down this page, "If a transaction creates a contract it will also contain the contract address."  https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.rst

Hopefully something on that page helps.

Comment: The call I was looking for was eth_getTransactionReceipt, given the transaction hash this provided the contract address in the result.

Comment: I had remembered to mine the transaction for some reason in the geth console if you get the transaction details it returns the object in my original question. For some reason you have to call eth_getTransactionReceipt through rpc to see the address the contract deployed to.

Answer (score 0):

its normal to be set to null (not yet mined) after creation (mining) your contract will get an address.

check : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction

```
to: String, 20 Bytes - address of the receiver.
     null when its a contract creation transaction.
```