# Can I send ether when a contract creates a new contract?

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to do something like

```
    registry = new assetRegistry.value(1 ether)();
```

?

This is particularly useful when the constructor function of assetRegistry calls the [ethereum alarm service](http://ethereum-alarm-clock.com), because the alarm service takes a fee

Comment: This is definitely possible in EVM -- you can create new contract and send some ether (called endowment in this context) to it in a single instruction. I would also like to know if that is possible in solidity.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Ether would be sent to [address 0](https://live.ether.camp/account/0000000000000000000000000000000000000000).  But what you can do is [pre-compute the address of the new contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/760/42) and send the Ether first, then have the contract create the new contract.  Highly advised to use testnet first, because coordination is required to make sure the correct account nonce, which would have to be provided from the outside.

Comment: Is there any way to get an account's nonce from inside a contract?

Comment: No, I was going to suggest it does need "outside" help to get the nonce...

Comment: Of course, you could code the contract to keep track of how many other contracts it's created, effectively keeping a duplicate nonce...

Comment: assuming a contract keeps track of its nonce, is there a solidity word for rlp_encode ? or a library ? example ```address precomputedRegContract = sha3(rpl_encode(this, nonce));```

Comment: https://github.com/androlo/standard-contracts#rlp might help