# Avoiding ownership cycles in contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-design, design-patterns

I am repeatedly facing this issue with structuring contracts' code:

```
contract Allower {
    Allowed allowed;

    function doSth() onlyallowed;

    modifier onlyallowed {
        if (msg.sender != address(allowed))
            throw;
        _
    }
}

contract Allowed {
    Allower allower;

    function doSthOnAllower() {
        allower.doSth();
    }
}
```

In order to enforce that only a particular instance of `Allowed` executes `Allower.doSth`, we need the contracts to keep mutual references (assuming we like the 1-1 relationship, but still want to keep these contracts separate). Now, to deploy both contracts and have them work, we need to add, more or less:

```
contract Allower {
    // snip...
    function Allower(Allowed _allowed) {
        allowed = _allowed;
        allowed.setAllower(this);
    }
}

contract Allowed {
    // snip...
    function setAllower(Allower _allower) allowernotset {
        allower = _allower;
    }
}
```

Is there any pattern which would allow to by-pass the necesity of `setAllower`? It just seems like an anti-pattern to have such "set" methods propagate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [here](https://github.com/ebuchman/evm-tools/blob/master/analysis/guide.md#stateful-evm):

> Note it gave us the new contract address. Where did this address come from? It is the sha3 hash of the RLP encoding of the list [address of sender, sequence number of sender].

If you know in advance at what tx nonce you will deploy `Allower` and you can make this RLP calculation yourself, then you can calculate the address to pass to the constructor of your `Allowed` contract. And vice-versa.

Let's reproduce [this Python script](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed) in Javascript:

```
#!/usr/bin/nodejs

var ethJsUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');

var account = "0x6ac7ea33f8831ea9dcc53393aaa88b25a785dbf0";
console.log("nonce0= " + ethJsUtil.bufferToHex(ethJsUtil.generateAddress(account, 0)));
console.log("nonce1= " + ethJsUtil.bufferToHex(ethJsUtil.generateAddress(account, 1)));
console.log("nonce2= " + ethJsUtil.bufferToHex(ethJsUtil.generateAddress(account, 2)));
console.log("nonce3= " + ethJsUtil.bufferToHex(ethJsUtil.generateAddress(account, 3)));
```

My interest spiked, I also created a small [Truffle project here](https://github.com/b9lab/cyclical-reference) where, for deployment I do:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    // You need to npm install -g ethereumjs-util
    var ethJsUtil = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/');

    var currentNonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
    var futureLeftNonce = currentNonce;
    var futureLeftAddress = ethJsUtil.bufferToHex(ethJsUtil.generateAddress(
        web3.eth.accounts[0], futureLeftNonce));
    var futureRightNonce = futureLeftNonce + 1;
    var futureRightAddress = ethJsUtil.bufferToHex(ethJsUtil.generateAddress(
        web3.eth.accounts[0], futureRightNonce));

    deployer.deploy(Left, futureRightAddress);
    deployer.deploy(Right, futureLeftAddress);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to what extent it would fix the problem, but one can consider putting the "1-1 relationship" to a separate contract, deployed prior to both `Allower` and `Allowed`.

```
contract Handcuffs {
    address left;
    address right;

    // set() must be called by both handcuffed contracts
    function set() {
        if (left == 0x0)
            left = msg.sender;
        else if (right == 0x0)
            right = msg.sender;
        else
            throw;
    }

    // once handcuffed, get() always returns the other contract
    function get() constant returns (address partner) {
        if (msg.sender == left && right != 0)
            return right;
        else if (msg.sender == right && left != 0)
            return left;
        else
            throw;
    }
}

contract Allower {
    Handcuffs allowed;

    function Allower(Handcuffs _allowed) {
        allowed = _allowed;
        allowed.set();
    }

    function doSth() onlyallowed;

    modifier onlyallowed {
        if (msg.sender != allowed.get())
            throw;
        _
    }
}

contract Allowed {
    Handcuffs allower;

    function Allowed (Handcuffs _allower) {
        allower = _allower;
        allower.set();
    }

    function doSthOnAllower() {
        var allowerContract = Allower(allower.get());
        allowerContract.doSth();
    }
}
```

An alternative to this would be to have the deployer call set explicitly, thus freeing `Allower` and `Allowed` from all responsibility:

```
contract Handcuffs {
    // snip...
    function set(address _left, address _right) onlydeployer onlyonce {
        left = _left;
        right = _right;
    }
    // snip...
}
```