# Generate contract address using nonce

Tags: contract-deployment, addresses, clients

Good day, I was looking at the way contracts addresses are created and it seems that the process is quite deterministic (depends on the nonce). Is there a way to get the address of a contract that **wasn't yet deployed** for a specific nonce? something like:

```
contractAddress = getAddress(nonce1, data, privateKey)
```

I know there used to be the pyethereum library that offered such tool, but it wasn't updated in a long time and I was hoping to use a more active tool.

As always, your help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `data`?  It also shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others can add other answers, but pyethereum is still active and this type code doesn't change:

```
def mk_contract_address(sender, nonce):
    return sha3(rlp.encode([normalize_address(sender), nonce]))[12:]
```

from [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)

The private key is not needed, only the sender address. However if the `sender` is unknown, from the OP's `privateKey`, `sender` is computed by:

```
def privtoaddr(x, extended=False):
    if len(x) > 32:
        x = decode_hex(x)
    o = sha3(privtopub(x)[1:])[12:]
    return add_checksum(o) if extended else o
```

Answer (score 3):

In golang, use [`ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto.CreateAddress`](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto#CreateAddress).

`func CreateAddress(creator common.Address, nonce uint64) common.Address`