# Predict a contract's deployment address

Tags: solidity

I have read it was possible to predict the address of a contract before deploying it.

Do you know how can this be possible ?

What happens if we send some Ether to this address before deploying the contract ?
Will this Ether be lost ? Or will it be affected to the contract ?

Thanks

Comment: The ether won't be lost, it will be ascribed to the contract. See bullet #3 in the answer to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/63987/16043).

Comment: With regards to predicting the address of a contract before deploying it - see the answer to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/760/16043).

Comment: So in short, your question is a kind of duplicate of the two questions aforementioned (not saying it's a bad one or anything).