# How to send ether to a contract (even if the contract doesn't implement receive or fallback functions)?

Tags: ether, balances, address.transfer, selfdestruct, send

If the contract doesn't implement the receive or fallback function as payable, it can't receive funds?

Answer (score 6):

***The last 2 ways listed for sending balance allow to send balance to a Smart Contract even if it doesn't implement receive and payable fallback functions:***

You have multiple ways to transfer balance from a Smart Contract to another (I'm going to list 5 of them):

- Using transfer function. Ex: `contractAddress.transfer(1 ether)`
- Using send function. Ex: `contractAddress.send(1 ether)`
- Using call function. Ex: `contractAddress.call{value: msg.value}("");`

To check the differences between these methods, [check this article](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-transfer-vs-send-vs-call-function-64c92cfc878a).

The first 3 approaches require that if the receiver is a Smart Contract, it needs to implement the `receive()` function or the `fallback()` function, both explicitly payable.

The recommended approach is using call (not transfer or send). To know why, check why the Access List feature was added in a previous network fork.

- You can also send balance from one contract to another account by using the SELFDESTRUCT opcode.
- And also it's important to know that you can transfer balance to a Smart Contract before its creation because Smart Contract addresses are deterministic over the address and the nonce of the deployer.

These two last considerations are really important because a Smart Contract can receive funds even without implementing `receive()` or `fallback()` functions.

Comment: Some more detail is here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63988/82179