# why cant smart contract receive ether like externally owned account without a receive/fallback function?

Tags: transactions, ether, contract-invocation, accounts

why do smart contracts requires a [receive](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/contracts.html#receive-ether-function) function to accept ether? what prevents the smart contract from receiving ether like an externally owned account(EOA) directly without any functions?
What was the design principle behind this?

Comment: Read: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63987/can-a-contract-with-no-payable-function-have-ether

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a contract with no payable function have ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63987/can-a-contract-with-no-payable-function-have-ether)

Comment: Mostly for security reason. In very old solidity versions contracts could accept ethers without requiring a fallback function that caused some issues for developers that weren't aware of that feature. Solidity developers decided that in order for a contract to accept payments it should enable it explicitly. It still possible to send ether to contracts without a receive function,.

Comment: @Ismael thanks i got it. there should be an EIP associated with the change, any idea which one is that? would like go in depth how the check is implemented.

Comment: @matank001 i understand there are certain ways to force ether but was looking for why contracts cant receive ether like EOA.