# Do i need to fund my contracts with eth

Tags: transactions, contract-invocation, function

I have a protocol composed of multiple contracts which interact with each other, when a user call a transaction in one of the contracts, the contract calls other contracts functions .
**The question is :** do i need to fund my contracts with eth so they can execute functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not.

The user who issues the transaction pays for the gas cost of the entire transaction. This includes any inner "sub" transactions which call subsequent contracts from the first contract. So whatever the user's transaction does, the user pays for it (unless the contracts have some code to add extra Eth payments along their calls, or something funny).

Usually contracts don't hold any Ether. Your contract also shouldn't accept any Ether unless it requires that. So as long as your contract doesn't have a `payable` function it won't accept Ether (except in [a few rare cases](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63988/31933)).