What are the ways in which ETH can be forcefully sent to a contract that doesn't implement the fallback function?
It is mentioned in the Solidity docs that there are several ways to forcefully send ETH to a contract:

Neither contracts nor “external accounts” are currently able to prevent someone from sending them Ether. Contracts can react on and reject a regular transfer, but there are ways to move Ether without creating a message call. One way is to simply “mine to” the contract address and the second way is using selfdestruct(x).

Besides self-destructs, what are the other ways in which this can be done?

As far as I know, there are at least three ways:

Selfdestruct
Target of validator rewards
Sent before contract exists (unsure if this counts in your case)

Source: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63988/31933
