# From an account's address is it possible to tell whether the account is a contract account or externally owned contract?

Tags: transactions, web3js, accounts, addresses, yellow-paper

I am trying to visualise transactions for Ethereum, currently, I know there are blockchain explorers such as [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) and [Etherchain.org](https://etherchain.org/), however I don't want to keep calling their API to get data, rather use my own full node to get all the data I require since it give me greater control.

So I set up a full node and use the Web3JS library to get blocks and transactions. However, the Web3JS doesn't have the option to get an account via given address (unless I am mistaken). So, once I have the transaction object, I can figure out who the sender and receiver are, but I also want to know whether the sender or receiver is a contract or an account. I know on etherchain's API we can get accounts using the address, is it possible to do the same using geth and Web3Js?

Ethereum's yellow paper mentions that each account has a nonce, balance, storageHash and codeHash, so I thought it would be possible to get an account using addresses from the blockchain. Please help we figure out how to determine whether a given address is a contract or an account, without using blockchain explorers mentioned above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to determine from the address alone if it is a contract account or an externally owned account.

See this previous post on how contract addresses are generated:

- [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)

Moreover it is expected that eventually all accounts will be contracts (this is called *account abstraction*):

- https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/28
- https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/24/understanding-serenity-part-i-abstraction/

You can use web3.js function [`web3.eth.getCode`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode) to get EVM bytecode associated with the address. It is assumed that for externally owned accounts it will return `0x0`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the notation I notice on etherchain, and was planning to do.

Comment: While the concept of an externally owned account exists, it will always return 0x0 for web3.eth.getCode.  (But 0x0 may also mean an account that just hasn't had a contract deployed to yet, so this comment is consistent with this answer.  So depending on how strict you want to be, checking the return value of getCode could be a sufficient approximation.)

Comment: The previous comment confuses me. If a contract hasn't been deployed yet at an address, then it is not a contract. In this sense, it seems to me that if `getCode` returns 0x0, then that address is clearly not a contract. Presumably, the OP is asking the question because he/she wants to know if an address that has interacted with his/her dapp is a contract (and perhaps behave differently). If it's already interacted, and getCode returns 0x0, isn't it true that it is not (and never will be) a contract? I'm not saying it is, I just confused by the previous comment.