# Can I redeploy a previous self-destructed smart contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, selfdestruct

If I deploy a smart contract, and then self destruct it. Then later send it ether by mistake, can I re-deploy it and be able to access that "lost" ether through the smart contract?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13458/is-there-any-way-to-re-deploy-to-the-same-address-a-contract-that-wasnt-deplo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the address of a contract depends on the nonce of the sender. As you are creating a new transaction, your nonce will be different and the contract will be deployed in a new address.

Comment: This may change with Constantinople and the introduction of [EIP-1014](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014)