# Reference Smart Contract Address in Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, addresses

Is there a way to know the address of the smart contract you are writing before deploying it? Or somehow reference the smart contract address in the smart contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract's address can be is generated based on the account nonce and account's own address: [How to deploy smart contract in predefined contract address in private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17927/how-to-deploy-smart-contract-in-predefined-contract-address-in-private-ethereum) . So you can calculate it in advance.

Or you can reference the contract's own address (whatever it is) in Solidity with `address(this)`.

P.S. New opcode `CREATE2` enables even more flexibility in knowing contract addresses in advance (but it's rather complicated): https://hackernoon.com/using-ethereums-create2-nw2137q7