# Why was RLP chosen as the low level protocol encoding algorithm?

Tags: history, protocol, rlp

Is this an ad-hoc decision? Why RLP? Is it specifically suited to something?

Comment: See the design rationale:  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#rlp

Comment: @dbryson Yes thought exactly as you as I was typing answer and not sure how it could be explained better than that source.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RLP was chosen because of **(1) simplicity of implementation, and (2) guaranteed absolute byte-perfect consistency.**

Source is [Ethereum Wiki:](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Design-Rationale#rlp)

> RLP is intended to be a highly minimalistic serialization format; its
>   sole purpose is to store nested arrays of bytes. Unlike protobuf, BSON
>   and other existing solutions, RLP does not attempt to define any
>   specific data types such as booleans, floats, doubles or even
>   integers; instead, it simply exists to store structure, in the form of
>   nested arrays, and leaves it up to the protocol to determine the
>   meaning of the arrays. Key/value maps are also not explicitly
>   supported; the semi-official suggestion for supporting key/value maps
>   is to represent such maps as [[k1, v1], [k2, v2], ...] where k1, k2...
>   are sorted using the standard ordering for strings.
>
> The alternative to RLP would have been using an existing algorithm
>   such as protobuf or BSON; however, we prefer RLP because of (1)
>   simplicity of implementation, and (2) guaranteed absolute byte-perfect
>   consistency. Key/value maps in many languages don't have an explicit
>   ordering, and floating point formats have many special cases,
>   potentially leading to the same data leading to different encodings
>   and thus different hashes. By developing a protocol in-house we can be
>   assured that it is designed with these goals in mind (this is a
>   general principle that applies also to other parts of the code, eg.
>   the VM). Note that bencode, used by BitTorrent, may have provided a
>   passable alternative for RLP, although its use of decimal encoding for
>   lengths makes it slightly suboptimal compared to the binary RLP.

Comment: Thanks all, I was unaware of the design rationale document.

Comment: By the way. I often see the phrase "RLP was *chosen*" but I don't see anything to suggest that RLP existed outside of Ethereum. Am I correct in saying that RLP was *designed* for Ethereum, and is specific to Ethereum? The Yellow paper specification does in fact recognize positive integers as part of the RLP spec, so it is not data type agnostic, and has special requirements for their encoding.