# How to differentiate payment transaction from contract transaction?

Tags: accounts

There are three types of transactions:

1. Ether transfer from one EOA to another
2. Contract creation
3. Contract call

2 can be easily identified since it's "to" field is empty. How to differentiate 1 & 3? [This post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29573/how-do-i-determine-whether-the-transaction-is-used-for-the-contract-creation) separates 2 from 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to differentiate between 1 and 3, you can check if there is any code at the `to` address.

```
if(web3.eth.getCode("0xa5Acc472597C1e1651270da9081Cc5a0b38258E3").length > 2){
  console.log("Sent to contract")
}
else{
  console.log("Sent to a externally owned address")
}
```

Comment: Why `> 2`, not `> 0`?

Comment: "0x" is present for externally owned account.

Comment: Oh, u mean `getCode().length > 2`.