# Get the amount of Smart Contracts hosted on the ETC blockchain

Tags: ethereum-classic, geth-debugging

I have a couple of questions:

1. How can I determine the amount of Smart Contracts that are hosted on the ETC blockchain?
2. Of these smart contracts, how many of them have been verified?

I guess geth is necessary for this, but I am not sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you define `verified` ?

Comment: @Nulik Good question. I think the scope of the question can be broadened to all smart contracts, regardless if they are verified or not. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the Ethereum (Classic) blockchain and a general block explorer. The **blockchain** simply holds the data and state of everything that has ever happened. A **block explorer** is a visual representation of all of the data from the blockchain, as getting data directly from the blockchain for every query is highly inefficient.

> how can I determine the amount of Smart Contracts that are hosted on
>   the ETC blockchain?

There are a few ways to do this, but will be difficult. The most efficient way would be to write a script that scans the blockchain for each instance of a contract creation.

You *can* use geth for this, but there are other options, if desired.

> Also, of these smart contracts, how many of them have been verified?

"Verified" is *strictly* a statistic created by the hosts of block explorers. **There is no such thing as a verified contract from the perspective of the blockchain**. I am not sure there is a block explorer that does Verify contracts for ETC.

Comment: Shane: thanks for your answer. I was already clear on the difference between a blockchain and a block explorer. Regarding the script: do you have any idea of doing it? Thanks again.

Comment: You can use [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29573/how-do-i-determine-whether-the-transaction-is-used-for-the-contract-creation) answer. If a transaction is sent to `0x00...` it could be a contract. If you check the receipt, you will see a contract address if it is a contract.