# Creating a contract ERC20 and sending a transaction, get balance (web3)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-deployment

This is my first time creating a contract. I need to create a TEST contract ERC20.

After researching I understand ERC20 is like an abstract class which tells which methods should be implemented in the contract.

Also I understand I need to create the contract using Solidity and I need to deploy it.

Questions:

1. Is a Token an instance of a contract?
2. Is it necessary to deploy a contract for testing purposes?
3. How do I deploy a contract on a test network and on a main? is it done through web3 API or do I need to do it through a Wallet?
4. Sender address is the same as the contract address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, it is. ([proof](https://www.ethereum.org/token))
2. Yes, but you can deploy it in your private chain, so you don't need to sync and waste time. Consider using [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js) btw.
3. It can be done both ways. You can deploy it through the web3 API in geth console for example or through the Ethereum Wallet app or on [MyEtherWallet.com](https://www.myetherwallet.com/) website.
4. No, it is not. You need the sender address and the sender nonce to compute the address of smart-contract.

> right(keccak256(rlp([account,nonce])),20)

Find out more about how addresses of smart-contracts are computed [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761/9938).

Comment: I am using this tutorial to create my contract: https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6. I see they create to contracts: simple and crowdsale, I guess I do not need the crowdsale?

Comment: can you help me with another question please? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34071/ethereum-parity-balance-0-and-same-nonce