# How to get blockNumber of contracts deployed with truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, dapp-development, dapps, truffle-migration

We deploy our contracts with `truffle migrate`.

We need the blockNumber of the contract deployment transaction in the webapp.

We could use `web3.eth.getTransaction(txhash).blockNumber()` but can't get txhash in the app because JSON files generated by truffle doesn't contain it.

How can I retrieve contract deployment blockNumber on front end app?

Comment: FE? If you have transaction hash of contract deployment or even contract address. You can paste the transaction hash on [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) to get the details like block number. timestamp, gas, gasPrice etc. If you are strict to use web3, use [getTrsancation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction) `web3.eth.getTransaction(txhahs).blockNumber()`

Comment: thanks. FE = front end (updated question)
Indeed I can see on etherescan. But I need to get it in my webapp.
we deploy with truffle, I couldn't find txhash in generated JSON artifacts

Comment: Was it deployed on testnet?

Comment: (clarified the question)
it's a deploy on rinkeby.

Comment: Do you have contract address?

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be this (if you use web3 prior version 1.0.):

1. You can calculate the deployed **contract's address** by knowing the
   address from which you sent the contract creation transaction and
   from the corresponding nonce. Check [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed) out!
2. Now you can create your contract instance since you have the abi and the contract address.
3. From the created contract's instance you can simply have txHash of the transaction which created it by accessing this field: **`myContractInstance.transactionHash`**

Answer (score 0):

Solution tested with truffle 4.x, use in your js:

`let block = await web3.eth.getBlock("latest")
console.log(block.number)`

Comment: This retrieves the latest block number, and may or may not be related to when the transaction creating the contract was mined.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information from the `networks` section of the json generated from the truffle migraton. By fetching the receipt for the `transactionHash`, you can get the **blockNumber** among other information.

`[Contract].json > networks > [networkID] > transactionHash`

alternatively from the `truffle-contract` instance.
`[truffle-contract instance].contractArtifact.networks.[networkId].transactionHash`

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract-schema/pull/19

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```js
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  const MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");
  await deployer.deploy(MyContract);
  const instance = await MyContract.deployed();
  const address = instance.address;
  const txHash = MyContract.transactionHash;
  const blockNumber = (await MyContract.web3.eth.getTransaction(hash)).blockNumber;
};
```