# What would happen if I would deploy contract as 1st and 129th transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, contract-deployment, raw-transaction

According to how contract address is [computed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) my 1st and 129th transaction as a contract deployment should have the same address. What would happen if I was to deploy them in that order?

I already tried with ganache but it refuses to send more than 128 transactions.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the 1st and 129th transaction would have the same address? That might help to formulate an answer.

Comment: @smarx I figured out I was missing some knowledge about `RLP` which led me to a wrong assumption. Please see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried in Ganache and able to create the same contract 2nd time on 128th block with different contract address.

```
SENDER ADDRESS
0xd23c8582A66f4a1e4696CCc3D6B085721123A8A9
CREATED CONTRACT ADDRESS
0xA826e724031d9698FB24e3C881Bebe55F1EB8F39
CONTRACT CREATION
VALUE
0.00 ETH
GAS USED
2282348
GAS PRICE
1
GAS LIMIT
2282348
MINED IN BLOCK
128
```

-

```
SENDER ADDRESS
0xd23c8582A66f4a1e4696CCc3D6B085721123A8A9
CREATED CONTRACT ADDRESS
0x6F2014378e4D34382CF93D906762FF2d12CdB769
CONTRACT CREATION
VALUE
0.00 ETH
GAS USED
2282348
GAS PRICE
1
GAS LIMIT
2282348
MINED IN BLOCK
1
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I really meant 129th. I corrected my question.

Comment: Let me fire back my ganache!!

Comment: `SENDER ADDRESS
0xd23c8582A66f4a1e4696CCc3D6B085721123A8A9
CREATED CONTRACT ADDRESS
0x6F2014378e4D34382CF93D906762FF2d12CdB769
CONTRACT CREATION
VALUE
0.00 ETH
GAS USED
2282348
GAS PRICE
1
GAS LIMIT
2282348
**MINED IN BLOCK
1**

SENDER ADDRESS
0xd23c8582A66f4a1e4696CCc3D6B085721123A8A9
CREATED CONTRACT ADDRESS
0xe54ff25e548d9D3A14C426c333aBE7E15CBFDE1B
CONTRACT CREATION
VALUE
0.00 ETH
GAS USED
2282348
GAS PRICE
1
GAS LIMIT
2282348
**MINED IN BLOCK
129**`

**It's created!!**

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't deploy for me and how the contract address gets computed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I believed 1st and 129th transaction should have the same address is because I missed a constraint on my `RLP` [implementation](https://github.com/BlockStoreApp/Web3Swift/commit/eec942f236f165bfd853a95360dd2b6acd886828). This caused number `128` to be encoded incorrectly as `0x80` instead of `0x8180` which caused me to believe 1st and 129th transaction should have the same address.

Since I was using my implementation of transaction signing it also obviously didn't work past 128th transaction on ganache.