# How to compute ethereum contract address with java?

Tags: addresses, web3j

I'm looking for the java version of the solution of this question.

[How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)

Actually I want have a solution of the problem below.

I have a master contract which creates many sub contracts.
And I need to get the addresses of the sub contracts when it's created.

master contract creates sub contract with a function like this

```
function createForwarder() public returns (address) {
    return new Forwarder();
}
```

But I can't get the address from this function. I'm using web3j and it has not internal transaction concept. So I need to get the address with another way.

What will be the best solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution in Java using web3j utilities.  We have to convert the address to a byte[], then encode, then Hash, then transform the output.  I've included my steps below.  Hope this helps!

```
    private String calculateContractAddress(String address, long nonce){
    byte[] addressAsBytes = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(address);

    byte[] calculatedAddressAsBytes =
            Hash.sha3(RlpEncoder.encode(
                    new RlpList(
                            RlpString.create(addressAsBytes),
                            RlpString.create((nonce)))));

    calculatedAddressAsBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(calculatedAddressAsBytes,
            12, calculatedAddressAsBytes.length);
    String calculatedAddressAsHex = Numeric.toHexString(calculatedAddressAsBytes);
    return calculatedAddressAsHex;
}
```