# Why I can't deploy a smart contract to a specific public key if i just generated and own this publickey/private key?

Tags: contract-deployment

I am writing an explorative article about the actors/assets model for Ethereum 2.0 (https://ethresear.ch/t/ethereum-2-0-data-model-actors-and-assets/4117).

Are there some reasons why is it not possible to deploy a smart contract to a specific public key if i've just generated and own this public key/private key?

Could we add this feature without breaking all the current Ethereum spec?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is "what would happen when you want to deploy a second contract to the same address?"

However [you can compute the address where a contract will be deployed](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761/20300) based on your address and its current nonce value.

Comment: nothing as we are not able to update a contract