# Call to smartcontract without address

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

Lately I had a conversation with someone who says that it is possible to make a call to the smart contract without giving the address. He said it's possible to send certain parameters and by them the call will find the smart contract and invoke given in the parameters method. I doubt it is possible but I would like to ask you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it is possible since you could have multiple contracts taking the parameters you're sending.
 However knowing the address of the person which deployed the contract you might be able to find the contract address. See this thread : [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: no, it's not possible.

Long answer: in theory someone can run whatever service to relay messages to a contract. So I could run for example a website at http://www.mycontract.com which knows the real contract's address and I can execute things on the website - in that way *you* don't have to know the address but *someone* has to (the service). So there has to be always some way to find the address as all transactions have to be sent to the contract's address (or to a proxy contract which again has to know the real contract's address).