# is account nonce network dependent?

Tags: addresses, accounts, network, nonce

In Ethereum, does Account nonce depend on network?

I mean for same address on different network, will there be different nonce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is Account nonce depends on network?

Yes. The nonce is part of the state data associated with each account. The state data will be difference for each different network you use the same address on (i.e. private key).

There is no way for one network's state data to be shared with another network.

Comment: so my first contract deployed on both networks will have same contract address?

Comment: Correct. A contract's address is generated deterministically. -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed (And is dependent on the nonce.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, nonce is relative to the number of tx you did in the network.

So if do `n` tx on mainnet your ropsten nonce will still be `0`.

Comment: so my first contract deployed on both networks will have same contract address?