# How to prevent the code of my contract being used in a CALLCODE?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, callcode

Simple question but I couldn’t find the answer anywhere.
How to know if the code of my contract is used in a CALLCODE or DELEGATECALL by third party since`address(this)`returns the address of the caller instead of the address of the contract if I’m not wrong ?

Comment: Of course, it’s possible that I’m wrong and `address(this)` returns always the same address even in a CALLCODE environment.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this?

Comment: @TjadenHess for the sole purpose of preventing third parties doing it.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple way**

```
uint private constant MAGIC = ...; // Your birthday here
uint private magic = MAGIC;

function isDelegated () internal view return (bool) {
  return magic != MAGIC;
}
```

The idea is that `MAGIC` is compile-time constant, so it will be embedded into the byte code by Solidity, but `magic` is state variable.  When contract is called normally, `magic == MAGIC` is true, but in case of `CALLCODE` or `DELEGATECALL`, your code will observe storage of the calling contract, thus `magic` will most probably contain something other than `MAGIC`.  Though this approach may be easily cheated by calling contract, so it protects only from accidental, but not from malicious use.

**Reliable approach**

You need to save real deployment address of your contract, and then in method you need to compare `address(this)` with saved address.  The problem is that you cannot save deployment address into storage, because storage will not be available when your contract is called via `CALLCODE` or `DELEGATECALL`, so you need to save deployment address into your smart contract's byte code.  It is possible to modify byte code in constructor of smart contract, though this will require some assembly programming.  Simpler way would be to modify byte code before publishing deploy transaction.  You will just need to predict contract address, which is actually possible, because contract address is derived from address of whoever deployed the contract and transaction nonce.  So, you need to do something like this:

```
function isDelegated () internal view returns (bool) {
  return address (this) != 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789;
}
```

And before deploying your contract you need to:

1. [Find out address the contract will be deployed at](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)
2. Replace `0123456789012345678901234567890123456789` in contract's byte code with this address
3. Deploy contract as usual but with modified byte code

And after this `isDelegated` will return accurate result.

BTW, [Solidity protects libraries form being called directly](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#call-protection-for-libraries), and I believe that is uses byte code modification in constructor technique, as described above, to achieve this.

Comment: No this won’t work because calling contract can trick the values. I don’t only want to check but prevent.

Comment: Usually, `address(this)` returns address of this contract, not calling one.  But in case this contract was called via `CALLCODE` or `DELEGATECALL` it returns address of calling contract, or, more precisely, it returns whatever it returned for calling contract.

Comment: **Reliable approach** is impossible to cheat

Comment: How to ensure `0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789` will be encoded in code and not as an ꜱꜱᴛᴏʀᴇ constent ?

Comment: All literals are always in code.  All store variables should be explicitly declared.  Solidity never puts anything into store by its own.

Comment: Also, as far I know, it’s not possible to get the address of the future contract if the contract is created by a contract.

Comment: It is indeed possible.  The address of created contract is derived from address of creator contract and nonce, where nonce is the number of contracts already created by this creator contract plus one.  See "Note" in the following answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761/4955