# CREATE / CREATE2 Verification

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, opcode

Where do I verify whether a contract has been created with `CREATE` or `CREATE2`, would I have to disassemble the contract and look for a `CREATE2` opcode in the contract creation code?

Answer (score 1):

At first, most of the contracts a created via transactions from externally owned addresses, i.e. backed by private key, and thus there are neither `CREATE` nor `CREATE2` opcodes involved.

For those contracts, that were created by another contracts, the easiest way to check would be the following:

1. Lets assume you need to check contract `A` created by contract `B` at block `N`
2. Obtain nonce of contract `B` as it was at block `N - 1`, lets call it X.
3. Obtain nonce of contract `B` as it was at block `N`, lets call it Y.
4. For every nonce in range `[X .. Y - 1]` calculate address of the contract that would be deployed with this nonce by `B` via `CREATE` opcode.
5. If some of the addresses calculated at step 4 is equal to address of `A`, then `A` was deployed via `CREATE`, otherwise via `CREATE2`.

Comment: How do I calculate the address? I found this addr = new memory[offset:offset+length].value(value) I'm not really sure how to interpret this expression. Thanks Mikhail

Comment: Check this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed

Comment: What is meant by 'nonce of contract as it was at block N - 1?'

Comment: This should be what `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(B, N-1)` returns.