# How the contract address being decide when deploy it in another contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

According to [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed), I know a contract address is decided by the hash of deployer address and nonce. How about the contract is deployed through another contract?

Answer (score 0):

In case of a contract the `sender` is the contract and the contract address is being used as `senderAddress` [eip-1014](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md#address-formula) discuss the same

Comment: How about the nonce?