# How much Ether does a Smart Contract Address hold before a Payable Instantiation?

Tags: solidity, addresses, balances, constructor

The following code always reverts to `"Contract must be empty"`.
But shouldn't `address(this).balance == 0` if the contract hasn't even been instantiated yet?

Maybe since the contract doesn't even exist yet, neither does it's address/balance?
Even then, I thought all solidity values are set to `0` by default...

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.5.10 <0.7.0;

contract test {
    
    constructor() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "User must submit a valid money amount");
        require(address(this).balance == 0, "Contract must be empty");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `address(this).balance >= msg.value` by definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(msg.value > 0, "User must submit a valid money amount");
```

This line ensures users are sending ETH along with their transaction. Any ETH being sent is automatically added to the `address(this).balance` and so the deployment always fails.

> Maybe since the contract doesn't even exist yet, neither does it's address/balance?

This is not actually correct. It's just a public key address even before creating the contract. In fact, you could precompute a smart contract address and send money to it before it was created: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761/33305. But as mentioned above this wasn't the problem in your code.