# Calculate deterministic address with Create2 when cloning contract with Factory pattern

Tags: solidity, factory, create2, clone

There is an existing [unanswered question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86974/how-i-can-calculate-deterministic-address-from-contract-clone-create2) from another author with the same problem, I am creating a more detailed one with the hopes both can be closed.

I have a solidity contract based on the ideas from [this post](https://blog.coinbase.com/usdc-payment-processing-in-coinbase-commerce-b1af1c82fb0#e539). Basically it is factory contract that allows the deployment of forwarder contracts. To minimize gas costs, after creating a forwarder you can create a clone of it.

I wish to calculate the address that will be generated using create2, which works well with the `createForwarder` function:

**ForwarderFactory.sol**

```
    function createForwarder(address forwardAddress, uint256 salt)
        public
        onlyOwner
        returns (Forwarder forwarder)
    {
        bytes memory bytecode =
            abi.encodePacked(
                type(Forwarder).creationCode,
                uint256(uint160(address(forwardAddress)))
            );

        assembly {
            forwarder := create2(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode), salt)
        }

        emit Deployed(address(forwarder), salt);
    }
```

**CalculateAddress.js**

```
let bytecode = `${forwarderBytecode}${encodeParam(
  "address",
  forwardAddress
).slice(2)}`;

function buildCreate2Address(creatorAddress, saltHex, byteCode) {
  return `0x${web3.utils
    .sha3(
      `0x${["ff", creatorAddress, saltHex, web3.utils.sha3(byteCode)]
        .map((x) => x.replace(/0x/, ""))
        .join("")}`
    )
    .slice(-40)}`.toLowerCase();
}
```

That works well. However when generating a new clone address, the previous `buildCreate2Address` function does not work anymore because the 2nd and 3rd parameter in the create2 function are different.

**ForwarderFactory.sol**

```
    function generateCloneAddress(address target, uint256 salt)
        private
        returns (address cloneAddress)
    {
        bytes20 targetBytes = bytes20(target);
        assembly {
            let clone := mload(0x40)
            mstore(
                clone,
                0x3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73000000000000000000000000
            )
            mstore(add(clone, 0x14), targetBytes)
            mstore(
                add(clone, 0x28),
                0x5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf30000000000000000000000000000000000
            )
            cloneAddress := create2(0, clone, 0x37, salt)
        }
    }
```

I am not quite sure if its the bytecode that is changing, or if its the `buildCreate2Address` that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the clone is created using the standard [EIP 1167](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1167.md), so it has a different creation bytecode than the original forwarder. So to calculate the deterministic address of the clone you either modify the bytecode parameter of the `buildCreate2Address` function, or you can implement the following function in your contract:

```
    function predictCloneAddress(address forwarderAddress_, uint256 salt_)
        public
        view
        returns (address)
    {
        address predictedAddress =
            Clones.predictDeterministicAddress(
                forwarderAddress_,
                bytes32(salt_)
            );

        return predictedAddress;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please clarify which modifications we need to apply to bytecode parameter. Your solution works well, but it requires contract call. I want to do the calculations entirely off-chain.

Comment: The runtime bytecode is `363d3d373d3d3d363d73bebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebe5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf3` with the bytes from indices 10 to 29 (inclusive) being the 20-bytes address of your cloned contract. You can the details here: https://blog.openzeppelin.com/deep-dive-into-the-minimal-proxy-contract/

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use [@openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol) to clone your Contracts.
You can predict clone address off-chain with this javascript function:

```
const { formatBytes32String, getAddress, solidityKeccak256 } = require('ethers').utils

/**
 * Computes the address of a clone deployed using @openzeppelin/contracts/proxy/Clones.sol
 *
 * @param implementation the address of the master contract
 * @param salt integer or string value of salt
 * @param deployer the address of the factory contract
 */
function predictDeterministicAddress(implementation,salt,deployer){
  let assembly = `3d602d80600a3d3981f3363d3d373d3d3d363d73${implementation.toLowerCase().slice(2)}5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf3ff${deployer.toLowerCase().slice(2)}${formatBytes32String(String(salt)).slice(2)}`
  assembly += solidityKeccak256(['bytes'],["0x"+assembly.slice(0, 110)]).slice(2)
  return getAddress(solidityKeccak256(['bytes'],["0x"+assembly.slice(110, 280)]).slice(-40))
}
```