# Is there a way to deploy contracts with circular reference in 2 steps using create2?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, create2

Circular reference meaning contracts know each other addresses. So instead of

```
deploy foo
deploy bar(foo.address)
foo.init(bar.address)
```

Use some clever tricks to have only 2 deploy steps without an additional call to `init`

Comment: [There you go](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761/16043).

Comment: @goodvibration so how can both contracts know each other addresses in your solution?

Comment: Using you account address and nonce, you can safely compute the address of the next contract that you deploy with this account.