# how to covert a string to a ether address (20 bytes)?

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I have tried to use sha3 but it return error since invalid address. Here is my code. The sha3 returns 32 bytes address. I wonder is there other function that returns 20 bytes .

```
var to_add = web3.sha3(str);
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: '0xC5b0f45d8533909a80eA45Ed2FC42bd36C1Cccac', data:str,to:to_add},function(err, transactionHash)
```

Comment: What's `str`???

Comment: `web3.sha3` seems pretty old BTW. Are you still on web3.js v0.x?

Comment: @goodvibration   str is user logging information. I need to store them in recipient(to address) . Yes I am using web3.js v0 since class requires that. thanks

Comment: What is its value, is what I meant to ask.

Comment: The value is not defined. It depends on which function user call. Bascially, the value can be "user a log in", or "user a log out "etc. So the length is not fixed

Comment: Why would `sha3` give you an Ethereum address though? Moreover, what exactly is this address going to be good for (since obviously, no one will know its private key)?

Comment: @goodvibration the address should be the logging information data. i need to store the data in address. The professor mentions use keccak256, so I find sha3 is keccak256 in web3. That's why i used sha3.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses are computed from a private key, see [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed). If you are trying to generate them from a random hexadecimal string it is very likely you will not be able to access the funds transferred.

If you already have an hexadecimal string that comes from a valid address and its checksum is incorrect you can fix it with [web3.utils.toChecksumAddress](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-utils.html#tochecksumaddress).

```
> badAddress = "0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
> goodAddress = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(badAddress);
> console.log(goodAddress);
0xaAaAaAaaAaAaAaaAaAAAAAAAAaaaAaAaAaaAaaAa
```