# how to deploy a smart contract on same address in ethereum and binance

Tags: contract-deployment, smart-contract-wallets

I have a challenge from my client that he wants to deploy a token contract on ethereum & binance but wants to have same contract address ?

He has proved to me that it is possible but has shared no knowledge of it ( zkp , ha ha :), ).

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 6):

If your deployment environment employs the `CREATE` opcode under the hood, The deployed contract address is going to be a function of the deployer's EOA and the nonce.

```
contractAddress = hash(deployerAddress, deployerNonce)
```

You could get the same contract address if you deploy the contract using the same wallet and the same transaction order (i.e., the contract creation TX is the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd, ... tx in that wallet on both chains).

Otherwise if the deployment environment is using [`CREATE2`](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014), the contract address is going to be a function of the init code of the contract (creation bytecode) and a salt value of your choosing. By allowing you to set any value for salt, CREATE2 allows you to pick the future address of a contract before it's deployed. To have the same deployed contract address here on every chain, you need to use the same machine to compile and deploy the same contracts. The compilation directory affects the init code on some environments like Truffle, that's why it's recommended to use the same machine. Also, any change in the contracts code would result in a different init code, so you should have a code freeze before deploying to any chain. You will also need to use the same value for the salt.

Comment: Your answer is conceptually correct, but the actual function used [isn’t](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761/23644) simply `keccak256`.

Comment: @dwardu I've edited my answer above to make it more accurate, and also included more info.