# how are we sending funds on polygon through contract

Tags: solidity, payable, polygon

I know it sounds like a basic question (it should be), despite that I could not find any clear reference to that in polygon's (Matic) docs on how does `payable(address).call` works

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

contract MyFirstPolygonContract {


    string private name;
    uint private amount;
    
    function sendFunds(address receiver) external payable {
        payable(receiver).call{value: msg.value}('');
    }

//set
    function setName(string memory newName) public {
        name = newName;
    }

//get
    function getName () public view returns (string memory) {
        return name;
    }
    
//set
    function setAmount(uint newAmount) public {
        amount = newAmount;      
    }

//get
    function getAmount() public view returns (uint) {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

I deployed this contract into Matic Mainnet in order to test `sendFunds` and quantify the amounts. I tried sending funds between two of my accounts `sender_addr`, `recv_addr`.

On Remix, I have chosen to send 1 ether on this contract (deployed on Matic). One Matic Token has been deducted from `sender_addr`. But the `recv_addr` received none !! It's been about 24 hours now. The transaction is not even shown on polygon scan !

It's worth noting that function `sendFunds` worked as expected on Mumbai testnet though.

**EDITED**:

The contracts are deployed in different networks  having the same address
`0x3918AaECf75aD253E0098fD0ee5C11d854BE9de6`

I did that exact transaction on the testnet `0.1 MATIC`
https://explorer-mumbai.maticvigil.com/address/0x3918AaECf75aD253E0098fD0ee5C11d854BE9de6/transactions  (this was successful)

While I did those two transactions added `1.001 MATIC` on the matic mainnet
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x3918aaecf75ad253e0098fd0ee5c11d854be9de6  (failed to send to `recv_addr`)

Comment: can you include your deployed contracts addresses of Matic and Mumbai both?

Comment: @hack3r_0m you made me notice something I did not before, they have the same address !! It's true the contracts are the same but I did not expect them to take the same address ?!

Comment: It is possible if deployer and nonce are exact the same (that's how contract address is calculated). check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed

Comment: I get it now, it's just weird that the nonce wasnt refreshed between deploy runs. Anyway, it's still doesn't affect the issue i am having because they are different networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your contract is **not** deployed on Mainnet.

It is deployed on [Testnet](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x3918AaECf75aD253E0098fD0ee5C11d854BE9de6#code), but on [Mainnet](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x3918aaecf75ad253e0098fd0ee5c11d854be9de6) there is no contract code associated with the address.

You should try to deploy it again on Mainnet. As you know, if you use the same address and same nonce as on testnet, you should have the same address for your Mainnet contract.

If you want to receive the MATIC that you sent to the address back, you should add a `withdraw` function to your contract that transfers all the contract balance to `msg.sender`. Otherwise, this MATIC will be lost forever.

EDIT: I think that [this](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x392179031da3012dac321703a29e4c9fbd26316b#code) is your contract on Mainnet. The address is not the same as on Testnet, althought they both start by 0x39! You called the wrong address on Mainnet.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that everything in the code was right, it was just remix that for some reason mixed up and made me call the test contract and send the real matic in to that unintended contract. I loaded the real contract into remix by address and the transaction was successful.

Comment: I cannot get the real matic wasted because I am not able to know the nonce that was used. Anyway you solved my issue which was related to getting the code done , despite that it was actually working anyway xD.

Comment: The nonce on testnet was 22 (you can see it on the contract creation transaction in the explorer). On mainnet, your last tx was nonce 9.