# How did two tokens deploy with same address across networks?

Tags: contract-deployment, evm

A few months ago I deployed a test ERC20 token, called `2BC`, to the Ethereum Kovan testnet.

This token can be found here: https://kovan.etherscan.io/token/0x938736ab99c0a46bbf8fe7fb06e6f0974902d581

Yesterday, I deployed a new ERC20 token, called `BREV`, to the Polygon mainnet.

This token can be found here:
https://polygonscan.com/token/0x938736ab99c0a46bbf8fe7fb06e6f0974902d581

**How on earth do these two tokens have the same contract address?**

Comment: because you have the same nonce on the Owner's account on both networks

Comment: @Nulik Does it not also depend on the code of the smart contract?

Comment: *\*/* no */*\* .

Comment: As said by Nulik if the networks use the same rules as Ethereum then the contract's address follows a formula that depends on parameters that a user can control, like address, nonce, init bytecode, etc.

Comment: @Ismael Would the init byte code not be different for two tokens with different names?

Comment: @DavidCallanan Read the first answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761 from the duplicate question. The init bytecode is the constructor, and it is used by CREATE2 opcode to calculate the address.