# is it possible to create smart contract with deterministic address (like CREATE2 does) from transaction itself (i.e. without proxy/creator smart c)?

Tags: create2

I found that

1. From [ethereum yellow whitepaper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

> Transaction contains fields:
>
> - nonce
> - gasPrice
> - gasLimit
> - to
> - value
> - v, r, s
> - init (contains "smart contract creation code" that should return "smart contract runtime code") OR data (arguments to call smart
>   contract, typically "solidity function name hash" and "function
>   arguments")

also

> There are a number of intrinsic parameters used when creating an
> account: ........, the salt for new account’s address (ζ) .....
>
> The salt ζ
> might be missing (ζ = ∅); ......
>
> If the creation was caused by CREATE2, then ζ = ∅.

2. The "smart contract initialization code" should

- copy code to memory
- using the RETURN(start_offset_of_memory, end_offset) return the "runtime code"

[image]

---

It seems like if I provide the "salt" (of course together with "init" and all other fields except of "data") field in transaction issued from EOA it will create smart contract with deterministic address (just like  CREATE2 opcode does)

But there is no such field "salt" for transaction, and I see that everyone create smart with deterministic address using "ProxyFactory smart contract" (OpenZeppelin [1](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.8/deploying-with-create2) and [2](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-sdk/blob/7d96de7248ae2e7e81a743513ccc617a2e6bba21/packages/lib/contracts/upgradeability/ProxyFactory.sol#L87) or [here](https://hackernoon.com/using-ethereums-create2-nw2137q7) the Deployer smart contract)

It seems like:

- IF EOA creates smart contract from transaction - smart contract will be created using CREATE approach implicitly
- IF smart contract creates smart contract - it can be created using CREATE or CREATE2 opcodes

Question: is it possible / why it's not possible to create smart contract with deterministic address from transaction itself without using ProxyFactory approach?

Comment: That's simply by design. CREATE2 can only be used by contracts.

Comment: Take a look at [deterministic-deployment-proxy](https://github.com/Zoltu/deterministic-deployment-proxy), it might the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Regular contracts also have a deterministic formula to calculate their address https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed.

Comment: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2470

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Thanks for commenting here! Also appreciate you editing to improve answers, just wanted to let you know that OP got confused by your edit at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/posts/761/revisions  No harm done :)  (I also missed it during review.)

Comment: Whops, sorry @eth. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: You might be interested in the option to craft a single transaction that creates, executes and destroys a proxy factory, but unfortunately that still means the resulting address will depend on the EOA's nonce...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tnx to Paul Razvan Berg

This is by design, that's what I wanted to hear

So when people like here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/761/82396 say

> For contract created by CREATE2 its address will be:
>
> keccak256( 0xff ++ senderAddress ++ salt ++ keccak256(init_code))[12:]
>
> Note that senderAddress can be either an externally-owned account (EOA) or a contract.

I will know that no, it cannot be EOA, because senterAddress is a address of factory

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for bringing my attention to this. I'm always happy to learn and also be corrected when I make a mistake; the linked one wasn't mine as we see from its revision history :)

Comment: Funnily enough it was I who added that note about `senderAddress`. Wow. Hoisted by my own petard.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg We appreciate all your contributions to this site! :) Interesting petard phrase too!