# The function createPair in UniswapV2Factory.sol creates the pair of token ETH/DAI but could anyone explain the code

Tags: solidity, blockchain, uniswap

```
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair) {
    require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
    (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
    require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS');
    require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'); // single check is sufficient
    bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
    bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
    assembly {
        pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
    }
    IUniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1);
    getPair[token0][token1] = pair;
    getPair[token1][token0] = pair; // populate mapping in the reverse direction
    allPairs.push(pair);
    emit PairCreated(token0, token1, pair, allPairs.length);
}
```

I am not able to understand what this line of code is doing

```
 bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
assembly {
    pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
}
```

any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)