# modify contract and deploy it with new address using hardhat

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat

I am new to solidity and I am using hardhat as a developing environment.
I want to change my contract code and deploy with a new address just for development purposes but every time I change some code and deploy it using `npx hardhat run --network hardhat scripts/deploy.js`. hardhat gives me the same contract address and I know my modifications didn't apply in the new contract.
can someone explain how to do this?

this is my deploy script:

```
async function main() {
  const NFTMarket = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarket");
  const nftMarket = await NFTMarket.deploy();
  await nftMarket.deployed();
  console.log("nftMarket deployed to:", nftMarket.address);

  const NFT = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFT");
  const nft = await NFT.deploy(nftMarket.address);
  await nft.deployed();
  console.log("nft deployed to:", nft.address);

  let config = `
  export const nftmarketaddress = "${nftMarket.address}"
  export const nftaddress = "${nft.address}"
  `

  let data = JSON.stringify(config)
  fs.writeFileSync('config.js', JSON.parse(data))
}
```

and this is the address I get for my contracts every time(same every time):

```
  export const nftmarketaddress = "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3"
  export const nftaddress = "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contract address is not determined by its content; it is deterministically computed from the address of the sender and the `nonce` of the transaction.

Each time you run your script, you are using the same sender (test address) with the same nonce (`0`), so the same address is computed.

If you use a separate node, let's say `geth` in dev mode, that remains running between multiple executions of your deploy script, you will see different addresses created each time, because the same user is used to deploy a new smart contract and the nonce increases.

See [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed) for more details.