# mint transaction before contract deployment

Tags: etherscan

Im looking for answer I deployed following contract:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x0e02e7596183e8ac9d4bd7c0a89a7fd7df42ad73

How is it possible that before I even deployed the contract mint transaction happened?

[image: wierd]

Is this bug in etherscan, or what is going on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Around that date someone has deployed a contract at the same address in Rinkeby https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0e02e7596183e8ac9d4bd7c0a89a7fd7df42ad73.

Having the same contract address in different blockchains is completely normal if you used the same private keys because they are deterministically calculated: [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed).

As the transaction my guess is that someone erroneously switched the network settings to mainnet before sending a transaction.

Comment: Sir, this make no sense to me. There is a mint transaction before contract creation, how is that related to testnet. Further more how is it possible that contract received ether before it existed?

Comment: @user224562 Transactions are just messages sent to an address, and at any time a message could be sent any address. To the blockchain sending a transaction to a contract address before it is deployed will be like sending a message to an EOA and it will be recorded in the blockchain but no side effect will be performed. The ether sent to an address before the contract is deployed will be available to the contract when it is deployed.