# I got the exact same address for a contract deployed on both bsc and ethereum testnet

Tags: hardhat, testnets, hardhat-deploy, binance-smart-chain, goerli

I deployed the same smart contract using hardhat on goerli ethereum testnet and binance testnet and i was surprised to see that they both have the exact same address...

How is that even possible?
Is it coming from hardhat conf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address is the same because you used the same deployer address and nonce. You can read more details [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed/137413?noredirect=1#comment157464_137413).