# Can I set the value of contract address to the value I want?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, evm

When I deploy a contract, a contract address is created.
At this time, can I set the value of address to the value I want?

Additionally, can anyone explain how the contract address is determined?

Comment: Simple answer - No you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that's possible. Generally, the contract address is determined from the sender's address and the number of transactions sent from that address, which is the nonce. But you can also create a contract using the new opcode, CREATE2, that was added in EIP-1014.

See:

[How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)

https://chainstack.com/deploying-a-deterministic-contract-on-ethereum/