# Do EVM contract addresses follow an order?

Tags: contract-development, polygon, arbitrum

I've noticed that if I deploy the same contract on Optimism, Arbitrum, and Polygon, they will all share the same contract address. Also, if I then deploy 3 contracts on Optimism, wait a bit, and then deploy those same three on Arbitrum as well, they will also have the same contract addresses.

Are contract addresses following a certain order? How does each EVM blockchain get the exact same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deploy from the same account with the same nonce on a different chain, it will have the same address once deployed.

[How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed/137413?noredirect=1#comment157464_137413)