# How to transfer funds from an address to another in solidity

Tags: solidity, tokens

I am working on crowdfunding website using the Ethereum blockchain that can create a campaign. I created an algorithm that creates a payable address, and it can be fundable.

```
function createMyFunDity(string memory _addressName)
        public
        checkDuplicateName(_addressName)
    {
        address caller = msg.sender;
        list_of_creators.push(caller);
        bytes32 hashedAddressName = keccak256(abi.encode(_addressName));
        hashedAddressList.push(hashedAddressName); // added  hashed to the array to comapre .
        bytes32 hashedString = keccak256(
            abi.encode(_addressName, msg.sender, block.timestamp)
        );
        address castedAddress = address(uint160(uint256(hashedString)));
        address payable funditeeAddress = payable(castedAddress);
        funditees.push(FunDitees(funditeeAddress, _addressName));
        listOfFunDityAddresses.push(funditeeAddress);
        nameToAddress[_addressName] = funditeeAddress;
        creatorToAddressCreated[caller] = funditeeAddress;
        addressCreatedToCreator[funditeeAddress] = caller;
    }
```

The problem right now is I can't withdraw from the address.

Comment: What exactly is the question?
What does address actually mean when you say I can't withdraw funds?
You want to withdraw funds from the smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

The function is randomly creating a 160 bits value that it is reinterpreted as an address. That is perfectly fine.

The problem is that to withdraw from an address it needs to be a contract with a withdraw function, or an EOA (external owned account) with a private key.

If you have to create wallets in a predictable way from an smart contract I'd suggest using CREATE2 opcode. Look at the answer for this question [How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed).